# Django ORM: Sum value and then create extra field showing rolling average

Tags: django, orm, sum, aggregate, annotate

Is it possible, using Django's ORM to create a Sum based on a Date column and then add an extra field with a rolling average.

Let's say I have a table like this, called "Sales":

```
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|     Date            |     Category     |     Value    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-01     |         1        |      55.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-01     |         2        |      30.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-02     |         1        |      25.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-02     |         2        |      85.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-03     |         1        |      60.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
|      2020-04-03     |         2        |      30.0    |
|---------------------|------------------|--------------|
```

I would like to group it by Date (column "Category" is unimportant) and add the Sum of the values for the date. Then I would like to add a rolling Average for the last 7 days.

I tried this:

```
days = (
        Sales.objects.values('date').annotate(sum_for_date=Sum('value'))
        ).annotate(
                rolling_avg=Window(
                         expression=Avg('sum_for_date'),
                         frame=RowRange(start=-7,end=0),
                         order_by=F('date').asc(),
                    )
                )
        .order_by('date')
```

This throws this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Avg('sum_for_date'): 'sum_for_date' is an aggregate
```

Any ideas?